# OnTriggerEnter2D changing an int only on the object it is triggered by in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code that subtracts 4 from an int called "flowerPoints" every time a player collides with an object. The code is applied to 7 Game Objects, but when the player collides with one of them the int changes only on the object it collided with.

```
[SerializeField]
public int flowerPoint;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    
    if(collision.tag == "Bee")
    {

        if (flowerPoint >= 4)
        {

            Invoke("startMakingHoney", 10f);
            flowerPoint -= 4;
        

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you've told it to do. Assuming that (your incomplete) code vaguely resembles what you're using, each copy of your MonoBehavior will have its own instance of `flowerPoint`. There's no such thing as a "global variable" in C#. You could use a `static` variable, but that's really frowned upon in Unity for a lot of very good reasons.

Comment: Well, It's working correctly. You can add this script to player, since the player is the one responsible for keeping track of the flowerPoint not the objects, logically. When flowerPoint is above five you can call a method with which the player has collided using collision.GetComponent<>().

Answer (score 0):

The int flowerPoint is subtracted every time a collision occurs. Maybe the flowerPoint int decreases below 4.